# Route standard Windows audio (MME, WASAPI, etc.) through specific ASIO device channels?

Tags: software, windows, asio

(apologies if this is off-topic for this forum - I looked around and this seemed the most appropriate!)

I have an audio interface / mixer (Zoom Livetrak L-8) with support for 2 independent stereo output channels from the connected computer (1-2 and 3-4). Its driver makes available both an ASIO and standard interface (not sure which exactly it supports but some of MME, WASAPI - the normal ones), and both can be used at once. However, given Windows' lack of (good) multi-channel audio support, the exposed non-ASIO interface goes to the first output channel (1-2).

What I would like to do is to be able to route *some* programs through the second output channel (3-4). This option is exposed in the ASIO device, but of course that is not accessible by most programs. So what I am looking for is something somewhat like [virtual cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) in how it exposes a standard audio device, but with ASIO-aware routing that can send incoming audio to specific ASIO channels. Does this exist, or is this use case just too niche?

Thanks!

p.s. Virtual cable isn't the best analogue, as I don't need its main feature of the virtual microphone - it's just the only program I know that exposes that sort of a virtual device.

Comment: We do get this type of routing on Windows query every so often - but as answers never seem to be forthcoming all I can imagine is that we're all on Macs ;) best I can do is this list of possible alternatives to Mac's Loopback - https://alternativeto.net/software/loopback/?platform=windows - & hope something in there might do it. ASIO is proprietary, though ASIO4ALL seems to have reverse-engineered it on Win. idk how that really works on Win, but even on Mac you need apps that can use either standard routing & therefore Loopback, or between asio apps, that can use ReWire etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That link reminded me about VoiceMeeter, which I by chance already had installed - and, using just that, I was able to get it set up! Admittedly, it's a bit of a precarious setup and (as all bad tech horror stories begin) I'm not 100% why it all works, but it does!

Comment: Glad it was some help. If you want to write up your research & discovery into an answer, that might help future Windows users who find themselves here.